# how to custom text editor in my helperform prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop

how to add **tinymce** editor in my own  module in prestashop when generating a form with helperform?

i have a simple prestashop module that displays  a simple data in displayhome hook

form module configuration tab with a simple text editor.

Now i want to make this textarea be a tinymce editor (But Now is simple textarea)

i've generated the form using heloperform class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the property `'autoload_rte' => 'rte'`:

```
array(
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'label' => $this->l('Field label'),
    'name' => 'field_name',
    'cols' => 8,
    'rows' => 4,
    'autoload_rte' => 'rte'
),
```